# My Navbar showing in the inspect element but not visually there

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to using react and tailwind there is a problem with my website if i go into the inspect element it shows my Navbar is there however it doesnt visually show. I have no error except for the tailwind which I am generally assuming it is that. Here is my code:

```
import  { useState } from 'react'
import {close, logo,menu} from '../assets'
import {navLink} from '../constants'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex py-6 justify-between item-center navbar">
      <img src={logo} alt="David" />


    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

In my index.css  it showed an error message

```
Unknown at rule @tailwind
```

If this doesent help please go on to my repo in github: https://github.com/cupitus/Reactjs-tailwind

What I tried was installing the tailwind in the terminal also I have tried importing it to the css. What i expected to happen is to see a black navbar arcoss the screen with David on it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Tailwind framework documentation for Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite), you have configured your project incorrectly.

Consider trying the following steps (these are covered in step 2 of the [Tailwind framework documentation for Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)):

1. Install `postcss` and optionally `autoprefixer`:

   ```
   npm install postcss autoprefixer --save-dev
   ```
2. Create a PostCSS configuration file:

   ```
   npx tailwindcss init --postcss
   ```

   If you chose not to install `autoprefixer`, you would need to remove the `autoprefixer` line in the `postcss.config.js` file generated from the command.